# How do i remove the exact time stamp after the date?

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DQZV.png)I have a column called created_at in the dataframe "accepted_opportunity": , i was wondering how i could remove the time values within my tables after the date?

For example:

```
 created_at
 11/18/2018 3:29:00 PM -> 11/18/2018
 2/21/2018 7:54:26 AM  -> 2/21/2018
 11/5/2016 12:44:16 AM -> 11/5/2016
 6/29/2018 2:26:28 PM  -> 6/29/2018
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `sub` here:

```
x <- c("11/18/2018 3:29:00 PM", "2/21/2018 7:54:26 AM", "11/5/2016 12:44:16 AM",
    "6/29/2018 2:26:28 PM")
out <- sub("\\s*\\d+:\\d+:\\d+ [AP]M$", "", x)
out

[1] "11/18/2018" "2/21/2018"  "11/5/2016"  "6/29/2018"
```

But, you would probably be better off storing your timestamps as an actual date type, e.g. POSIXCT.  Then, you would be able to leverage an API to extract only the date portion.

Comment: I have over 200000 of those, is there any otehr way?

Comment: @AK `sub` is vectorized, q.v. my updated answer.  I only used a single value initially to avoid typing out all your sample data.

Comment: I tried running it but all it did was create new values. Didn't change the dataset.

Comment: You need to reassign to your vector/dataframe, e.g. `x <- sub("\\s*\\d+:\\d+:\\d+ [AP]M$", "", x)`